# NumberFormatException при вызове Integer.parseInt() не во всех случаях и при непустой валидной строке

Tags: java, android, biginteger

Что за Exception выкидывает? 
Вот участок кода на который ругается.

```
  55  StringBuilder quotientStr = new StringBuilder();

  56  quotientStr.append(arrOfVar[2]);**//добавляем число из массива**
  57  quotientStr.append(5);
  58  int quotient = Integer.parseInt(quotientStr.toString());

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "4090303030"
    at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:495)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:527)
    at TaskTwo.division.LongDivision.intermCalc(LongDivision.java:58)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Проблема в том, что вы вышли за границы максимальнно возможного значения содержимого переменной типа `int`, кое равняется `2147483647`, т.е. `2млрд+`. А у вас `4млрд+`.
<s>Таким образом, например, вы не можете поместить всё население нашей планеты в переменную `int`. А вот население Китая вполне поместится в такой переменной. И программа такая будет работать исправно ровно до тех пор, пока Китай не присоединит к себе Индию. Только представьте: вы играете в к-л игру за Китай, развязываете n-мировую войну, побеждаете и присоединяете к себе Индию... А вместо сообщения "Поздравляем, теперь коммунистов в мире `2млрд+`!" ваша игра вылетает на рабочий стол! Ибо в такой игре захватить Индию невозможно безнаказанно)</s>

**Решение:**

Для таких больших чисел надо использовать класс `BigInteger`, передавая вашу строку в его конструктор:

```
BigInteger quotient = new BigInteger(quotientStr.toString());
System.out.println(quotient);
//в вашем случае без проблем выведет 4090303030
```